# Mercurial (hg) can't access file ='FRX'

Tags: windows, logging, mercurial, diff

On my home laptop with *Windows 7 x64* (*NTFS*) some of mercurial repositories become *stuck* after unknown reason. The problem is when I try to run `hg log` or `hg diff`:

> Can't access file
>   D:\user\my-hg-repo-root-path\='FRX'

In same time, `icoming`, `pull`, `update`, `push`, `add`, `commit` work well.
So, last several days i live without history or diff preview on the home laptop.

I've not found any reason for such a problem, as same as what **FRX** means. Do you know the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PagerExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PagerExtension)?

That's where this `='FRX'` might be coming from. Look at your `~/.hgrc`.

Comment: definitely! that was the problem! thx a lot. paging in Mercurial on Windows makes me mad - i can't find any normal solution, like paging in git

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a file that has been created by some windows application (from http://www.file-extension.com/files/FRX/: *"As a binary form file, the FRX file extension can be found working with Visual Basic."*) probably during an execution of VB programs, and it could be possible that you do not have the read rights on this file.

If this file is not important for you, I'd suggest to remove it from the working directory, maybe using admin rights.

Comment: there is no any file/link/directory with such a name in the repository. I've never had such files before and i've never used VB or anything related. I just used. I've never had such problems in any other directories and any other VCS on the laptop, but only with hg second time ((

Comment: If the file does not exist (and is not hidden or something) I cannot make any sense of the error message.. sorry..